# Angular lifecycle hooks and rendering components

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Consider the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use the `app-footer` hook `ngAfterViewInit()` to append a script to the html which contains `jQuery` that handles elements in the `app-header` component, will work?

When does the `app-header` hook `ngAfterViewInit()` is executed compared to the `app-footer` hook?
Will it be executed first? Asynchronously?

Comment: Just wondering, why? This sounds like an XY type of question

Comment: I'm playing around with Angular and one of those themes I picked uses a jQuery plugin which does something similar to what I described. But my main goal is to understand when the lifecycle hooks get executed, comparing to other components.

Comment: Why not try placing console.log() in both and seeing which order they fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think it unwise to try to depend on the order and timing of the execution of lifecycle methods in multiple components, since that order and timing is not gauranteed.

Even if you get that working in your development environment, it is unlikely to work exactly that way on other clients, on all browsers, and with future versions of Angular.

It would be much safer to simply depend on the parent component's afterViewInit lifecycle method, during which it is guaranteed that the two children will have been initialized.

Second, I believe that it is generally recommend to not access the DOM directly, but to do so through a Renderer. Using jQuery violates that recommendation. You should probably look for an Angular-specific way to do what you need instead of using jQuery.

Comment: That third paragraph closed it for me, has I didn't yet thought of using the parent component's hook. And I'm indeed trying different Angular-specific alternatives.

Comment: Actually,  i think that components lifecycle callback order is guaranteed on a parent child level